# I can't download garageband sounds I purchased

Tags: macbook-pro, garageband

I installed Garageband 10.0.3 on my MacBook Pro 2013 when it was running Mavericks. I then purchased the additional sounds. I delayed downloading them all because at the time I didn't need them right away. I installed Yosemite, and now want to download them, however when I go to GarageBand > Download More Sounds the option is grey and clicking on it does nothing. I tried signing into the Appstore and opening Garageband through there, and it didn't work. I've restarted Garageband several times but with no luck. I'm wondering if I need to reinstall it, however I'm not quite sure how to do this. If anyone knows how to fix this, please let me know. If you need more information or this question needs to be edited, please let me know. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you using the same Apple ID? Checked in Purchases?

Comment: I am I only have one Apple ID, and I have only ever used that one on this computer.

Comment: Checked in Purchases?

Comment: Never mind, it seems to be downloading now. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Never mind, It's not working. :(

Comment: I reinstalled GarageBand, I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: You still didn't say whether you checked in Purchases, in the App Store.

Comment: This is what I did: I went into the App Store on my Mac, I made sure I was signed into my Apple ID, then I clicked on "Purchases", and saw GarageBand there. I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but I'm still having the issue. :(

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved try downloading again.

Source: Apple Support

Comment: Just download them again.

Comment: Can you please specify? When I go into the appstore there is no option to reinstall garageband. If you mean download the INSTRUMENTS again, that's my issue. I can't. The option to download them is greyed out. That's my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and contacted Apple Support.
They told me that there seems to be a problem with a server and that I should try again in the next days.

Comment: Thanks, for the response. It has been several days though, so I don't think that'll work.